# Need Form Value Responses on Original Page, not Redirected Page

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I inadvertently posted revisions to this previous post when I meant to update subsequent post that has GqlQuery code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't understood how web requests work. You can't "stay on the same page", because a POST - even if it's to the same URL - is a *request* for a new page. It's up to your code to render that *entire* page, complete with headers and formatting, including the new values.

This of course is why you should use a proper templating engine, rather than building up your HTML manually. Jinja2 is available in GAE, you should use it to render your template on both GET and POST.